# Dynamic TRect Draw

Tags: delphi

I am trying to simple thing. But i couldn' t :(

I have an TImage, which  name is overview. 
I want to draw a rectangle which is on the overview but independent from overview. So i added a TImage front of the overview and drawed a rectangle. Rectangle works but i just can see the TImage or overview. I tried to giving a transparency to rectImg but rectImg completely disappear.

```
   with rectImg.Canvas do
      begin
        Pen.Color:= clRed;
        Rectangle(0, 0, rectImg.Width, rectImg.Height);
      end;
```

I draw on a paint, what i want to make.
[image]

That rect can be resizable indepented from img.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Did you set the brush style to `bsClear`? Did you read the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Rectangle

Comment: Is this VCL or FMX ? Besides, I see no benefit of drawing on a canvas that is supposed to be static. Better choice would be e.g. paint box here.

Comment: vcl, @DavidHeffernan i ll read

Comment: should i use 2 TImage for this? One for this overview and the other is Trect, is that true?

Comment: I never understand the desire to add more and more image controls. If you must use an image control then use only one. Often using `TPaintBox` is a good option, allowing you to draw on demand.

Comment: that timage which have trect, cover the overview. So i could not see the overview when i put the top of overview image. But i also want to see overview.

Comment: I no longer have any confidence that I understand what you want. I cannot understand any of your comment. Never mind. I'll let others try to help because they might understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you effectively want to visually frame the image without drawing the frame on the original graphic itself, i.e. `rectImg.Picture` should not return a framed graphic. Two ways immediately come to mind:

a) Dump `TImage` and use `TPaintBox`, manually maintaining the core graphic and doing any stretching or whatever via method calls rather than property settings on the component.

b) Extend `TImage` to have an `OnPaint` event that gets raised after `TImage` has done its standard painting.

With respect to (b), you can do it either as an interposer class or a custom component. As an interposer class you could do this:

1) Re-declare `TImage` immediately above your form class:

```
type
  TPaintEvent = procedure (Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas) of object;

  TImage = class(Vcl.ExtCtrls.TImage) //use class(ExtCtrls.TImage) if pre-XE2
  strict private
    FOnPaint: TPaintEvent;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  published
    property OnPaint: TPaintEvent read FOnPaint write FOnPaint;
  end;

  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  //...
```

2) Implement the `Paint` override as so (slightly fiddly as `TImage` redefines the `Canvas` property of the base class):

```
type
  TGraphicControlAccess = class(TGraphicControl);

procedure TImage.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(FOnPaint) then
    FOnPaint(Self, TGraphicControlAccess(Self).Canvas);
end;
```

3) Declare a suitable event handler in the form class:

```
procedure rectImgPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
```

4) Implement the handler like so - note you need to set `Brush.Style` to `bsClear` to not create a filled rectangle:

```
procedure TMyForm.rectImgPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, rectImg.Width, rectImg.Height);
end;
```

5) Assign the event handler in the form's `OnCreate` event:

```
procedure TMyForm.ImagePaint.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  rectImg.OnPaint := rectImgPaint;
end;
```

I leave converting the interposer class to a custom component as an exercise for the reader...

**Postscript**

Two other thoughts now I think of them:

- Oddly enough, FMX is actually nicer here because its `TImage` provides a `OnPaint` event as standard.
- If it is literally just a frame you want, a codeless alternative would be to overlay the `TImage` with a `TShape`, setting the shape's `Brush.Style` property to `bsClear` as we did in the coding solution. In that situation, set the shape's `Enabled` property to `False` if you have any `OnClick` or `OnMouseXXX` handlers assigned to the image.